# Fill a half circle animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations, css-shapes

[image: css animation fill half circle]

I have seen this animation from Yahoo Weather app. I think it's cool and I would like to make it.

Now I created half circle and make the sun run along the curve path using css keyframe

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotatekey {
from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

.rotate {
-webkit-animation-name: rotatekey; 
-webkit-animation-duration: 7s; 
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

but I want to know how to make the yellow area **fill the half circle using css** and javascript? outside half circle is transparent area.

Comment: You already did animation with code above ! :) whats the problem

Comment: the problem is how to make the yellow area growth from left to right follow the sun.

Comment: I'm no CSS specialist, but I'd prepare two images: one with empty half-circle and second with filled one. Then put one on another and manipulate their widths.

Comment: why dont you make a div with round corners and overflow hidden as the half circle and put the yellow surface as div inside, animate it from left to right or in width from 0 to 100%? no image needed

Answer (score 4):

You can achive this effect using keyframe animations. In this demo, I used a pseudo element to create the **filling shape and animated the width** of that pseudo element to "fill" the parent :

```css
.wrapper {
  border-top-left-radius: 500px;
  border-top-right-radius: 500px;
  width: 500px; height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px dashed gold;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px; height: 100%;
  background: gold;
  -webkit-animation: fill 7s linear infinite;
  animation: fill 7s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fill {
  from { width: 0; }
  to { width: 100%; }
}
@keyframes fill {
  from { width: 0; }
  to { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: i would create a seperate div because :after may lack in compatibility

Comment: @Alex, browser compatibility for pseudo elements is very good (http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent) and goes up to IE8 I think that it is good enough to use it on most projects. + OP is using keyframe animations witch aren't supported even by IE9 so I think browser support for pseudo element is irrelevant to OPs situation.

Comment: @web-tiki I try and it's work fine for me! Thank you! I would like to ask you more question, how can I like the sun move with fill half-circle accordingly?

Comment: @Giffary how is the sun animation triggered?

Comment: @web-tiki check my code http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/JhxsT/

Comment: @Giffary this is the fiddle I wrote, maybe you forgot to fork/save you modification?

Comment: @web-tiki Opps! sorry, i forgot to create a new one. here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/3w4nb/ and here is yours http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/JhxsT/

Comment: @Giffary check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/3w4nb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="semicircle">
    <div class="fill"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #AAA;
}
.wrapper .semicircle {
  border: 2px solid #AAA;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper .semicircle .fill {
  background: rgba(200, 192, 32, 0.5);
  width: 0%;
  height: 200px;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper .semicircle:hover .fill {
  width: 100%;
}
```

demo: http://cssdeck.com/labs/pbnpqheh

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative where the yellow is rotated through instead of filling laterally:

HTML (hooray for pseudo-elements!):

```
<div id="horizon"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#horizon:before {
   content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: transparent;
    border:5px dashed #eee;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#horizon{
    width:410px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#horizon:after {
   content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
    background: yellow;
    -moz-border-radius: 400px 400px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 400px 400px 0 0;
    border-radius: 400px 400px 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom;
    transform-origin: bottom;
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: rotate; 
    -moz-animation-duration: 5s; 
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    from {-moz-transform:rotateZ(180deg);}
    to {-moz-transform:rotateZ(360deg)}
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from {-webkit-transform:rotateZ(180deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform:rotateZ(360deg)}
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mp4sZ/